# Test Class not found in selected project in Eclipse

Tags: android, junit3

I am trying to run JUnit test with Robotium framework in Eclipse, getting error as:

> Test Class not found in selected project

Comment: do you have robotium jar in your lib folder:TestProject/libs/robotium-solo-3.1.jar

Comment: import the jar into the libs directory of the test project and then adding it to the Build Path Libraries:

TestProject Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libreries -> Add JARs... -> TestProject/libs/robotium-solo-3.1.jar

Comment: jdniki !did`nt helped...